# Why is the observable decorator not respecting the debounce property?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Taking this binding and declaration

```
<input type="text" value.bind="houseNumber" keyup.delegate=" validation.validateField($event) & debounce:400"/>
```

And this viewModel

```
export class Test{
    @observable houseNumber; 

    constructor(){
        this.houseNumber = "";
    }

    houseNumberChanged(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log('changed');
    }
}
```

Normally the `debounce` property should delay the update of the binding: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/3

But somehow when I use the `@observable` decorator this `debounce` property is ignored.

### Update

I worked around this by using `updateTrigger`

```
<input type="text" value.bind="houseNumber & updateTrigger:'blur'" />
```

Still I'm curious if there is anyway to delay the binding with the @observable decorator so that the `houseNumberChanged` function is not called directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put the debounce on the binding where it needs to be (`value.bind="houseNumber & debounce"`). If you want to debounce the binding and only trigger on keyup, then you'll need this:

```
<input type="text" value.bind="houseNumber & debounce:500 & updateTrigger:'keyup'" />
```

I've created a quick example gist here: https://gist.run/?id=2621b818abcf64c512a6da6d8c1dd1a4

Answer (score 2):

I would check out this blog post.

https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/

it looks like the syntax your going for its actually:

`<input type="text" value.bind="houseNumber & debounce:400" />`

or if your wanting to go based off of the keypress event

`<input type="text" keyup.delegate="houseNumberChanged($event) & debounce:400">`